# What is "tongue to a sentence" of N & L sound?

Tags: sentence-construction, pronunciation

Ok, 1 teacher of mine once said in a class that "use tongue to a sentence to practice pronunciation" (I am not sure I heard  correctly, "tongue to a sentence" or something like that)

For example, to practice /u:/ /k/ & /g/ sound, you can learn to say this sentence out loud

**How many cuckoos could a good cook cook if a good cook could cook cuckoos?**

My question is that can you give me a similar example but this time is for practicing "N & L sound".

Maybe, "Nood likes nuts like a naughty noob". But seem this sentence does not make any sense.

COuld you come up with a different example of a sentence like that?

Comment: I suspect the word your teacher used was [*tongue-twister*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-twister).

Comment: _Nine nimble nobles nibbled nuts,_ might help with /n/. You can find thousands of tongue-twister sites, with entries sort by letter. [**Here**](http://www.rudolphacademy.com/educational-poems/esl-poems/esl-audio-tongue-twisters/l-blend-tongue-twisters/) is a page with several which are intended to help with /l/. Try a Google search for "tongue twisters for /l/ and /n/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it

> 1. You’ve no need to light a night-light
>
>    On a light night like tonight
>
>    For a night-light’s light’s a slight light
>
>    And tonight is a night that’s light
>
>    When a night’s light like tonight’s light
>
>    It’s really not quite right
>
>    To light night-lights with their slight lights
>
>    On a light night like tonight

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *could, good,* and *cook* don't have /u:/, they have /ʊ/, a completely different vowel.

This is /ʊ/:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-back_rounded_vowel
This is /u/: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_back_rounded_vowel

Your cuckoo sentence is pronounced:

> /haʊ mɛni kʊkuːz kʊd ə gʊd kʊk kʊk ɪf ə gʊd kʊk kʊd kʊk kʊkuːz/

Secondly, those pronunciation-exercising sentences are called [**tongue twisters.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-twister) Tongue twisters are phrases contrived to be difficult to pronounce as you are exposed to it, such as the famous "*She sells sea-shells on the sea-shore.*"
Now, your direct question: "Make a tongue-twister for /n/ and /l/", here's what P.E. Dant said in your comments:

> Nine nimble nobles nibbled nuts, might help with /n/. You can find thousands of tongue-twister sites, with entries sort by letter. [Here](http://www.rudolphacademy.com/educational-poems/esl-poems/esl-audio-tongue-twisters/l-blend-tongue-twisters/) is a page with several which are intended to help with /l/. Try a Google search for "tongue twisters for /l/ and /n/".

[What is "tongue to a sentence" of N & L sound?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101491/what-is-tongue-to-a-sentence-of-n-l-sound/101496#comment199595_101491)

**The point of using tongue twisters for pronunciation exercises is to be contrived to be hard to pronounce so that you can improve on them,** ***and consequently the sounds the twister contains. I think you can make up your own, as you've already done.***

Comment: It's very strange to see a link to a question in the answer to _the same question._ Is this an intentional Godëlian ploy which is too subtle for my addled mind?

Comment: Or /ˈkuːkuːz/, with the same vowel in both syllables.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I was linking to your comment!